# Terraform: Can I set variable type = any dict/object

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to allow any type of dictionary/object as an input variable?

I have a module to create cron expressions with lambda and I'm trying to add a variable to take in a dictionary to pass into the resource call.

I'd like just allow any dictionary of any length. With any type for the keys and values in it.

Initially, I tried just:

```
variable vars {
  type = object
}
```

But that isn't allowed.

Right now I just have the type empty, so it will accept anything, but that doesn't seem like good practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally this would be the complex type `map(any)` to specify it must be a `map` with `any` type nested. However, you state that:

> I'd like just allow any dictionary of any length. With any type for the keys and values in it.

Unfortunately there is a stipulation that `map(any)` type for a variable declaration must have a consistent structure across all values for the entries.  Therefore, you could use `map(any)` if the input structure is consistent like:

```
{ 
  "one" = { "a_key" = "a_value", "another_key" = "another_value" },
  "two" = { "a_key" = "value", "another_key" = "the_value" },
}
```

However an inconsistent structure:

```
{ 
  "one" = { "another_key" = "another_value" },
  "two" = { "a_key" = "value", "another_key" = 0 },
}
```

would force the `any` type, which is the least restrictive and what you stated you did not want, but it is your only option in that situation.

Comment: Since in this case lambda only allows strings and numbers in it's envs, this is actually perfect. Thank you for the additional info about the caveats nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

You can just it like this

```
variable vars {
  type = any
}
```